# C# String to date with CultureInfo

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a date in the following format.  It is always in this format.

```
yyyyMMdd  ->  20130912
```

I need to convert it to a date.  But I need to be sure that the date is converted to the correct date format of the PC.  Cultureinfo.InvariantCulture.   Here is what my code looks like now.

```
DateTime parsedDateTime;
int year = Int32.Parse(rows[row][4].ToString().Substring(0, 4));
int month = Int32.Parse(rows[row][4].ToString().Substring(4, 2));
int day = Int32.Parse(rows[row][4].ToString().Substring(6, 2));
DateTime value = new System.DateTime(year, month, day);

bool DateTimeParseFail = DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDateTime);

if (!DateTimeParseFail) {
   msg = "Data Feed Convert string to DateTime: Date " + rows[row][4].ToString() + " - " + value.ToString();
   ComponentMetaData.FireError(0, ComponentMetaData.Name, msg, string.Empty, 0, out pbCancel);
   throw new Exception(msg);
}  else {
   buffer[colIndex] = parsedDateTime;
}
```

This just looks like overkill to me and I suspect that I'm over-thinking it.  There has to be an easier way of doing this.  But everything I have tried hasn't worked like I expected it.

Comment: erm... you have a date time here `DateTime value = new System.DateTime(year, month, day);` I have no idea what the point to the rest of your code is...

Comment: What is the desired output date format you want? US? m/d/yy ?

Comment: You've said you *always* want to use the format `yyyyMMdd` - so isn't that "the correct format"? It's really unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need to convert it to the users DateFormat.  Thats american format if the user has a PC with Europen format it needs to be formated like that.

Comment: @LindaL: you said `Cultureinfo.InvariantCulture`, which is NOT the user's date format. You will most likely want to use `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string dateText = rows[row][4].ToString();
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateText, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string result = date.ToShortDateString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

Note that I'm assuming your assertion that the date is *always* in this format is correct. If it's not, you'll find that the code throws an exception.

(The code you've posted suggests that your assertion is not true, because you've got a fallback format and some failure handling there...)

Answer (score 1):

Use the TryParseExact of DateTime....

```
var dateString = "20130912"; //rows[row][4].ToString()
DateTime parsedDateTime;
var DateTimeParseFail= DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDateTime);

if (!DateTimeParseFail) {
   msg = "Data Feed Convert string to DateTime: Date " + rows[row][4].ToString() + " - " + value.ToString();
   ComponentMetaData.FireError(0, ComponentMetaData.Name, msg, string.Empty, 0, out pbCancel);
   throw new Exception(msg);
}  else {
   buffer[colIndex] = parsedDateTime;
}
```